# Can't find element with selenium? (Tried implicit and explicit waits)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

I am new to programming and extremely new to web scraping. I need to scrape a table from a web page, where the table is displayed after a video.
As I said on the title, I tried implicit waits like:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
...
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_td")
```

(I tried the same with the xpath)

and explicit waits:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH("path...")
```

(tried the same with class name)

This is what I get:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

I would REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure you got the right element path or class name?

Comment: Yes. I've tried the same with elements that are displayed at the same time of the table (just to check) and unfortunately get the same results

Comment: What website is it? Also check if it's under an iframes.

Comment: It's this website: https://ficeda.com.mx/index.php?id=precios I am trying to scrape the "Abarrotes" table

Comment: If you go to the developer tools you will see that there are iframes.

Comment: Just checked and I think it is under an iframe as you said! Does wait.until not work with iframes?

Comment: You want to driver.switchTo()  to the iframe element.

Comment: the wait will work but we need to focus the iframe element.

Comment: Ok I will try it and update you once it (hopefully) works!! I can't thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0):

There is an iframe we need to switch to so do this prior to looking for your elements.

```
 iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')

 driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```